# Python - How can I add sound to an MJPG file?

Tags: python, opencv, video-editing

I vould like to add sound to my new made .avi file. My program edits every frame in orginal video and then puts them back together using this command :**cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')** (thats how the new .avi file is created). But the problem with the new file is that it doesn't have any sound, so *I vould like to add sound from the original file into this new .avi file*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `cv2`/`opencv`. Use `ffmpeg` to mux audio on top of your video generated.

```
ffmpeg -i cv2_generatet_video.avi -i you_sound.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.avi
```

Comment: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python use python binding and call the above command in code os use  python `sys` to call the os command